# Is there a way to automatically assign an issue in JIRA when DONE to the user who changed the status to WIP?

Tags: automation, jira, status, issue-tracking

I am looking for a smart value for Jira automation, that would auto-assign an issue when its status is changed to DONE to the user, who worked on this issue - a user who moved the issue from sprint backlog and changed the status to Work In Progress.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

I tried smart value {{initiator.displayName}}
I hoped it would assign the issue once DONE to the user who moved the issue to WIP, but it returned an error after the first test
Assign issue
Error assigning issues
ISSUE NUMBER: (Specified user does not exist or you do not have required permissions)

I do have the permissions as it is not my first automation rule in the given project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create new custom field 'Developer' (or any other name you like) and store there a user, who changed the status of the issue to Work In Progress. Once you triggered 'status changed' event to DONE, assign the issue to the user stored in 'Developer' field.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you happen yo know how to create a custom field and store there a user as per your recommendation?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I'm Jira user, not an admin :(
Ask your Jira admins to add new field )